# Jfxtrans mouseutil draggable limit to a region

Tags: jfxtras

I am developing a JavaFX application, used `jfxtrans.mouseutil` to make an anchor pane draggable, I want to bound or limit the draggable area to its parent, parent is also anchor pane.

I have tried to bound draggable area with checking the layoutx and layouty of the draggable pane but not working any solution?

My code:

```
MouseControlUtil.makeDraggable (testpane, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        testpane.setLayoutX(1);

    }
}, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JFXtras?

Comment: jfxtrans to make draggable object in javafx application. i need to limit the draggable area.

Comment: jfxtrans ... jfxtras... not the same?